# ruby on rails will not generate model

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I am trying to generate a model in rails. 
I write:

rails generate model Post content:text

And it won't do anything. I don't even get an error message. Only the warning about using fiddle but I don't think that should stop me. I am using windows and Ruby version 2.0 . I know it's suppose to say create etc but it literally says nothing. Please help. I can't even move on

Answer (score 3):

First run

```
spring stop
```

Now, try to generate model

Answer (score 0):

Ruby use rails to create some steps.

For creating is:

```
rails g model post
```

Or try:

```
rails generate model post
```

However check if you installed ruby correctly use this is your command prompt:

```
ruby - v
```

And then check if rails was installed in your command prompt:

```
rails -v
```

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried generating your rails app first?

```
rails new myApp
cd myApp/
rails generate model Post content:text
```

This will now generate the desired code. You must be inside a rails directory to run the appropriate commands.

If you "rails new myApp" command does not generate output and a folder, then you do not have rails installed.

Answer (score 0):

So that works when i create my app using

```
rails new myapp
```

however when i went to a meetup and they were helping me get started they told my to start an new application using

```
rails new myapp -O - T
```

the addition of the -O -T was probably what was holding me back from creating the model because once i removed it i was able to generate a model. Does anyone have any idea what that -O -T stands for and its implication when creating an app? 
but anyway besides that my model is now working:)